# Major Google Maps glitch using API V3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

edit: this is now solved, see my answer below

---

The situation:

1. User clicks on a map-image
2. google maps API V3 is loaded via
   ajax
3. the map is shown in a dialog window
   / lightbox

What happens:

The map displays and all functionality works however there's a glitch with the top-left 'square' of the map.

I'm stuck!

---

edit: now with code:

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {          
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.448359,-2.590559);
            var options = {
              zoom: 13,
              center: latlng,
              mapTypeControl: false,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }; 

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.448359,-2.590559),
              map: map
            });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: The first time I visited your site (Safari 5) it was fine, but on subsequent visits I see what you mean! I think the marker changed colour from red (when it worked) to blue (when it didn't) as well...can you post some code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Alphonso for pointing me in the correct direction.

The problem is in the dimensions of the map div, even though `#map_canvas` had a height and width applied via css in the top of the document, it would seem the google maps API initializing before the style was being applied (this theory could be tested with dynatrace).

***Easy solution:**

1) inline styles for width and height*

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 700px; height: 400px"></div>
```

2) delay the loading of the map with `setTimeout()`

Answer (score 3):

I think that the problem is that the map initializes before the resizing animation has finished and so it thinks that it's smaller.

Try to make it adjust its size after the loading effect has finished:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

(you'll have to keep a reference to the "map" object