# Google Maps loading strangely

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, position

I'm using the Google Maps API (v3) on my website to show a map centered in a certain position.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-22.924484, -43.208001);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-property2"), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
});
</script>
```

At the end of my `<head>` I have:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Here's the result:

[image]

As you can see it's like there's two maps there.. But **if I resize the window the map is fixed**!

There's another problem: See the very top left corner of the map? This is the **location of `latlng` variable**.. That should be the center of the map, but it load as the top-left corner. :/

Ps.: There's no error or warning on my Firebug JS console.

---

I found a solution here: [Major Google Maps glitch using API V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536998/major-google-maps-glitch-using-api-v3/3538254#3538254)

And testing it I discovered another thing: I'm trying to load the map on a hidden div (not the map canvas, but the container that has it) that is shown when I click on a tab menu.

If the map load (using `setTimeout`) when the tab is active and the container is visible, the map loads ok.

I'm goin mad... really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because you can't load the map with the container hidden... My solution was load the map after the tab is shown, with this code:

```
$('ul.tabs li a[rel="location"]').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-22.924484, -43.208001);
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-property2"), {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: "Property location"
        });
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have a map in a hidden div and then decide to show the div you need to trigger the resize event on the map.

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you've already found the answer, but I've found 2 more interesting solutions:

[Problems with Google Maps API v3 + jQuery UI Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428178/problems-with-google-maps-api-v3-jquery-ui-tabs)

[Keep a Google Maps v3 Map hidden, show when needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360494/keep-a-google-maps-v3-map-hidden-show-when-needed)